# Prove/disprove that $U$ and $V$ are disjoint.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $x \neq y, -y$ and $|x| = 1 = |y|$, and take $r = \min \{ |x - y|, |x + y|, 1\}$. Let $U = \bigcup_{0 \neq \lambda \in \mathbb{R}}{B_{|\lambda| r}(\lambda x)}$ and $V = \bigcup_{0 \neq \lambda \in \mathbb{R}}{B_{|\lambda| r}(\lambda y)}$. I'm trying to prove that $U$ and $V$ are disjoint by assuming that $z \in U, V$, which implies that there exist nonzero $\lambda_{x}, \lambda_{y} \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|z - \lambda_{x} x| < |\lambda_{x}| r$ and $|z - \lambda_{y} y| < |\lambda_{y}| r$. But I'm stucked at this point because I don't know how to arrive at a contradiction. But $U$ and $V$ being disjoint is only a hypothesis, and so $U$ and $V$ might not be necessarily disjoint. I really appreciate it if someone could give an idea/hint on how to prove this, or if someone could come up with a counterexample.

Comment: There is maybe a problem if $x=-y$. Are you ok with $r=0$?

Comment: @FShrike sorry. It is supposed to be $x = y, -y$. I'll edit it. Thank you.

Comment: Should there be a factor of $1/2$ inserted in there, to make $U$ and $V$ disjoint? Aren't you sort of asking whether two cones of half-angle $\alpha$ are disjoint when their centers are separated by $\alpha$?

Comment: @BrianTung yes yes. I just realized that there should be $1/3$ in $r$ because that's how I originally defined it. I edited it. Thank you.

Actually, I want to separate $x$ and $y$ by two disjoint "somewhat" open cones, hence I have defined $U$ and $V$ that way.

Comment: SouravGhosh: Why did you revert @Shuichi's edit?

Comment: Changing $r$ to $\frac{1}{3}r$ make my answer useless. Changing question after accepting answer is not a good idea at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $\Bbb{R}^2$ and $x=e_1=(1,0)$ and $y=e_2=(0, 1) $

Then $\|x\|=\|y\|=1$ and $r=1$

$U=\bigcup_{\lambda\neq 0}  B_{|\lambda | r}(\lambda x)=\bigcup_{\lambda\neq 0}B_{|\lambda|}((\lambda ,0))$

$V=\bigcup_{\lambda\neq 0}  B_{|\lambda | r}(\lambda y)=\bigcup_{\lambda\neq 0}B_{|\lambda|}((0,\lambda))$

---

Claim: $U\cap V\neq \emptyset$

$z=(1, 1) \in U\cap V$

$z\in B_{|\lambda|}((\lambda ,0))$ for $\lambda=2$ and $z\in B_{|\lambda|}((0,\lambda ))$ for $\lambda=2$

$\|(1, 1) -(2, 0) \|=\|(1, 1) -(0, 2) \|=\sqrt{2}<2$

Comment: Hi. I edited the question. I forgot to put $1/3$ in $r$.

Comment: I posted the revised question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4518997/prove-disprove-that-u-and-v-are-disjoint-revised. Thank you.

Comment: Why did you revert @Shuichi's edit? Was it because they posted the corrected question under separate cover? I think it probably should've been kept here, since it's just a correction, rather than a new question, but I suppose it's not a big deal either way.