# Prove/Disprove that $U$ and $V$ are disjoint (revised).

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I posted a similar question: [Prove/disprove that $U$ and $V$ are disjoint.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4518636/prove-disprove-that-u-and-v-are-disjoint/4518682?noredirect=1#comment9491719_4518682) But I forgot to put $1/3$ in $r$. Here's the revised question:

Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $x \neq y, -y$ and $|x| = 1 = |y|$, and take $r = \frac{1}{3} \min \{ |x - y|, |x + y|, 1\}$. Let $U = \bigcup_{0 \neq \lambda \in \mathbb{R}}{B_{|\lambda| r}(\lambda x)}$ and $V = \bigcup_{0 \neq \lambda \in \mathbb{R}}{B_{|\lambda| r}(\lambda y)}$. I'm trying to prove that $U$ and $V$ are disjoint by assuming that $z \in U, V$, which implies that there exist nonzero $\lambda_{x}, \lambda_{y} \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|z - \lambda_{x} x| < |\lambda_{x}| r$ and $|z - \lambda_{y} y| < |\lambda_{y}| r$. But I'm stucked at this point because I don't know how to arrive at a contradiction. But $U$ and $V$ being disjoint is only a hypothesis, and so $U$ and $V$ might not be necessarily disjoint. I really appreciate it if someone could give an idea/hint on how to prove this, or if someone could come up with a counterexample.

Comment: Each of $U$ and $V$ are solid double cones radiating out from the origin (which is excluded from them) in the directions of $x$ and $-x$ for $U$ and $y$ and $-y$ for $V$. Because the intersections of these cones with the unit hypersphere are smaller in diameter than half the distance from $x$ to $y$ or $-y$, those intersections cannot overlap, and since at any other radius from $0$, the picture is the same except for scale, the cones do not overlap anywhere. I.e., they cannot intersect. That is the geometric intuition. It can also guide you in an algebraic proof.

Comment: As for getting around your block, divide your two inequalities by $|\lambda_x|$ and $|\lambda_y|$ and consider the point $\frac{z}{|z|}$.